# How to control $scope.$watch iteration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, gridster, angularjs-watch

I am trying to control the $scope.$watch function. Currently, I am having an infinite loop on my iteration.

```
$scope.$watch('dashboards', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.dashboard = $localStorage.sample;
        $scope.dashboards['1'].id = $scope.dashboards[1].id + 1;
        $localStorage.sample = $scope.dashboards[1];
        console.log('newval: '+$scope.dashboards['1'].id);
    } else {
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage;
        $localStorage.sample = $scope.dashboards[1];
        $scope.dashboard = $localStorage.sample;
        $scope.dashboards['1'].id = $scope.dashboards[1].id.length + 1;
        $localStorage.sample = $scope.dashboards[1];
    console.log('oldval: '+$scope.dashboards['1'].id);
    }
}, true);
```

Here's my scope.dashboards:

```
$scope.dashboards = {
        '1' : {
            id : '1',
            widgets : [{
                code : "bla1.html",
                col : 0,
                row : 0,
                sizeY : 1,
                sizeX : 2,
                title : "Bla1"
            }, {
                code : "bla2.html",
                col : 2,
                row : 0,
                sizeY : 2,
                sizeX : 2,
                title : "Bla2"
            }, {
                code : "bla3.html",
                col : 0,
                row : 4,
                sizeY : 1.5,
                sizeX : 2,
                title : "Bla3"
            }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that everytime there is a change in the position of widgets inside my $scope.dashboards I will store a new ID in thhe localStorage to save its positions state so as when the browser is closed/refresh it will still have its session/positions retained. Maybe you got an idea on how will I be able to work on this? Thank you!

Comment: You're causing an infinite loop because every time `$scope.dashboards` variable changes and $watcher is fired you change it again.

Comment: @NewDev are there any workaround you might know?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do and why you need to change $scope.dashboards on every change of $scope.dashboards.

Comment: Try to avoid changing the value of your $scope.dashboards on the else statement. As others have said it's firing the infinite loop

Comment: What I am into is getting the $scope.dashboards object where in the positions of my widgets on my dashboard are stored. So, I'm incrementing the id and that id will serve as my identifier that the json object was changed lets say somebody drag and drop a widget into another place.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that by assigning a different value in the $watcher (of `$scope.dashboards`) to the value being $watched, you're causing an infinite loop.

You should either avoid using the `$watch` as the trigger to update the `$scope.dashboards.id` and use the actual trigger that caused the change in the widgets. (Off-topic, but the use of the property `id` is slightly awkward - id has a very specific meaning, I would change it to "version" or something along those lines)

Or, the other option is to $watch only the `widgets` property, instead of a deep-watch of `dashboards`.

```
$scope.$watch("dashboards['1'].widgets", function(newVal, oldVal){
 ...
}, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

A rough outline of an approach you can use is as follows:

```
var modificationInProgress = false;
$scope.$watch('dashboards', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (!modificationInProgress) {
    modificationInProgress = true;
    // modify dashboards
  }
  $timeout(function() {
    modificationInProgress = false;
  }, 0);
});
```

If you're expecting dashboard to be modified multiple times in the same tick, this might cause some interesting bugs. But, if you're only expecting dashboards to be modified once per tick (say, when a user clicks a button), this should work.

But - your code is odd. I think that refactoring it to avoid watching and modifying the same variable is probably your best move. For example, you might want to watch a different object and store the number of times they were moved on a separate object, avoiding the infinite loop problem.